# Live agent disconnection of a chat

Tags: liveagent, redirect, chat

3 weeks ago I deployed Live agent in a Salesforce org.
Since then, everyday, all day long, there are about 5 agents in the console waiting for someone's chat contact. Recently, we have been starting having problems: when a chat between the agent and the visitor has already started  suddenly this chat session disconnects and  redirects to an other online agent. I didn't set any timeout in the org, Consequently, two identical leads are created in SF.
This is a big problem for my customer. Why they disconnect? Is this an IP problem? How can I solve it or making a workaround?

Comment: It is an old question. Stil may I know how id you resolve this. our instance is getting the same issue.